# If statement is not triggering the event

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I am working in ASP.net for the first time so I do not know if it is the if statement that is broken or if there is something weird between client server that I do not understand yet.... Below will be my server side and client side code. I have my code writing to a log file so I know that I have the correct syntax in my If statement. What this program does so far is that there are two drop down list the selection from the first will determine what is in the second. Using hard coded values for test first before switching it to a SQL datatable. Right now I select the first value and nothing happens. Any help figuring out what is not working with this is appreciated.

Server Side

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using FIS_DashBoard_Web.cs;

namespace FIS_DashBoard_Web.www
{
    public partial class PSBSecondary : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        Utils ut = new Utils();
        protected void ddlLine_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ddlLine.SelectedItem.Equals("WSM2"))
            {
                ddlBuiltProduct.Items.Add("GFE Control Board");
            }
            ut.WriteToLog(ddlLine.SelectedItem.ToString());
        }
    }

}
```

Client Side

```
    <div style="text-align: right;">
    <asp:Table ID="Table2" runat="server">
       <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell Text="Line"/>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLine" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlLine_SelectedIndexChanged">
              <asp:ListItem Value="WSM1" Text="WSM1"/>
              <asp:ListItem Value="WSM2" Text="WSM2" />
              <asp:ListItem Value="Pillarhouse 1" Text="Pillarhouse 1"/>
              <asp:ListItem Value="Pillarhouse 2" Text="Pillarhouse 2"/>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell Height="20" Text="What Product Was Built?"/>
            <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBuiltProduct" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">

                </asp:DropDownList>
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Errr. the _first_ value is `WSM1`? So, that does not equal `WSM2`. So the `if` condition is not met.

Comment: Could you define the listitems like this: `<asp:ListItem Text="WSM1" Value="WSM1" />` improved the readability. Put a breakpoint on the if-statement, to see if the selectedItem is really equal to `WSM2`.

Comment: Set breakpoints, step through your code and inspect your variables.

Comment: @RenéVogt Its a drop down list that checks the if statement everytime the Index has changed. So the ` if ` statement is met when you select the WSM2.

Comment: Of course, but you said "Right now I select the first value and nothing happens". Anyway, I guess @Leopard is right.

Comment: @Max Thanks for the suggestion for the improved readability did not know i could do it that way. It is changed.

Comment: @RenéVogt Oh ok I see what you were saying. Sorry that was an error my question. I did have the If equal to WSM1 at first but then changed it. So I forgot that it changed when i wrote the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SelectedItem.Text`

```
if (ddlLine.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("WSM2"))
{
  ddlBuiltProduct.Items.Add("GFE Control Board");
}
```

Comment: Not to seem ignorant but isn't that what I am using?

Comment: @DisarmedDevo I think you are now comparing a string against a ListItem object. Inserting `.Text` grabs the `Text` property, which is a string. This is the string defined at `<asp:ListItem Value="WSM2" Text="WSM2" />`

Comment: @DisarmedDevo you were comparing `ListItem` with `string`  now you are comparing `string` with `string`

Comment: @DisarmedDevo If you want to compare the `Value` property instead of the `Text` property, you could use: `ddlLine.SelectedValue` or `ddlLine.SelectedItem.Value` (both are the same).

Comment: @DisarmedDevo yes `.Text` is `string`

Comment: @DisarmedDevo `.Text` doesn't convert the ListItem to a string. Both `Text` and `Value` are string properties on the `ListItem` object. By saying `ddlLine.SelectedItem.Text` is like saying: Get the Text property of the current selected item.